# (recv() == 0) means disconnected or timed out? (sockets, Linux&Windows)

Tags: sockets, recv, setsockopt

I have set a timeout on my blocking socket ..

```
DWORD to = 1200;
if (setsockopt (soc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&to, sizeof(to))) {
    ...
}
```

In the case that recv () then returns zero, how can I tell this is link disconnected or read timed out?  If it's t/o I would like to read more, if it's discon I would like to take other action.  I realise I could just remove the t/o, then I would know it's discon, but I also need to routinely monitor how the read process is progressing.

Any help much appreciated. Cheers - Rich

Answer (score 3):

From the `SO_RCVTIMEO` section of the man page for `socket`:

```
...if no data has been transferred and the time‐out has been reached,
then -1 is returned with errno set to EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK, or
EINPROGRESS (for connect(2)) just as if the socket was specified to
be non‐blocking.
```

From the man page for `recv`:

```
These calls return the number of bytes received, or -1 if an error
occurred.  In the event of an error, errno is set to indicate the
error.

When a stream socket peer has performed an orderly shutdown, the
return value will be 0 (the traditional "end-of-file" return).

Datagram sockets in various domains (e.g., the UNIX and Internet
domains) permit zero-length datagrams.  When such a datagram is
received, the return value is 0.

The value 0 may also be returned if the requested number of bytes to
receive from a stream socket was 0.
```

A call to `recv` will return `0` on disconnect, or if a zero-length datagram is received, or if the requested number of bytes is `0`.

A call to `recv` will return `-1` on any error, including a timeout. You need to examine `errno` to differentiate between a timeout versus some other error.

Comment: From experience of my project. If connection was not purely closed (e.g. removed cable) and taking into accout settings from question, errno will yields unfortunatelly EAGAIN in both situations disconnect and time-out 